# CSS style not applied when using Angular ngRepeat

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, lightbox

I'm trying to use Lightbox to display images:

```
<div class="t-body tb-padding">
                <p class="c-black m-b-20">Images</p>

                <div ng-repeat="images in selectedItemToView.images">
                    <div class="lightbox row">

                        <a href="/user/2" class="col-sm-2 col-xs-6">
                            <img src="/user/2" alt=""  />
                        </a>

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="lightbox row">

                    <a href="/user/2" class="col-sm-2 col-xs-6">
                        <img src="/user/2" alt=""  />
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I have two DIVs, one with ngRepeat, and one without it. I'm displaying the same image. The images are displayed correctly, but when I click them, the images displayed with ngRepeat just downloads. The image outside works correctly, displaying the image in the Lightbox fashion (doesn't download).

I looked at the stylings applied and they both appear to have same CSS styles applied.

When I removed ng-repeat from the DIV, it works fine. So somehow using ngRepeat is causing Lightbox not to work.

Request headers:
With ng-repeat:
[image]

Without :
[image]
Any idea?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you compared the request headers for the images?

Comment: @John I looked at the headers and theres a difference but I don't know what to make of it. I added the header info to the post. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want your ng-repeat in the same div than the one with the class `lightbox row` ?

Comment: @ippi thank you but that is a little too advanced for my level. I think I will go with vanilla code for now. Cheers.

Comment: @floribon tried that but still same result. Thank you.

Comment: @madu Could you put together a pen/fiddle maybe?